# Injecting JQuery function in Objective-c in UIWebView

Tags: javascript, jquery, objective-c, xcode, uiwebview

**I have this function in jquery saved as doc2.js in my Target and i had copy in my bundle resources as follow:**

**doc2.js:**

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $(".flip").click(function(){
  $(".panel").slideToggle("slow");
     });
       });
```

**at my Xcode i have the following:**

```
 UIWebView * webView = [[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
 [webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"new" ofType:@"html"]isDirectory:NO]]];
 webView.delegate=self;
 [self.view addSubview:webView];
```

**and this method :**

```
-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
 NSString *jqueryCDN = @"http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js";
 NSData *jquery = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:jqueryCDN]];
 NSString *jqueryString = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithData:jquery encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
 [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jqueryString];
 NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"doc2" ofType:@"js" inDirectory:NO];
 NSData *fileData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
 NSString *jsString = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithData:fileData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
 [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsString];}
```

**In my html file:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
    <head>        
         <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
         <style type="text/css"> 
             div.panel,p.flip
            {
                 margin:0px;
                 padding:5px;
                 text-align:center;
                 background:#e5eecc;
                 border:solid 1px #c3c3c3;
             }
             div.panel
             {
                 height:120px;
                 display:none;
             }
             </style>
     </head>
     <body>    
         <div class="panel">
            <p>Any Thing.</p>
            <p>Any Thing.</p>
         </div>        
         <p class="flip">Show/Hide Panel</p>
            </body>
 </html>
```

**this code should handle the UIWebView but its not working with me
I think that my jQuery function is not completed or something like that
Any idea ??**

Comment: I'm new at stack overflow and my mother tongue is Arabic so i have a little problem writing in English , any way thanks for your answer

Comment: I'm pretty much half-arabic myself...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to try a different approach: Either include a local copy or download jquery from a cdn. Doing both seems unnecessary.

Moreover: Just define a javascript function in your doc2.js, include the file in the HTML and call it directly within Cocoa. Make sure you exposed your functions to Cocoa with

```
isSelectorExcludedFromWebScript
```

Calling is possible with

```
evaluateWebScript
```